# pygame vector checking if vector2 length == 0 not working?

Tags: vector, pygame

So I am trying to check if a vector2 in pygame has a length of 0, and if that is not the case I want to normalise and multiply it by a number.

Here is the relevant code:

```
if direction.length() != 0:
    velocity = direction.normalize()
    rect.center += velocity * speed
```

Both velocity and direction are Vector2s.

However, this code always triggers and gives an error that it cannot normalise a Vector with the length of 0.

However, when I change it slightly to:

```
if direction != pygame.math.Vector2(0,0):
    velocity = direction.normalize()
    rect.center += velocity * speed
```

then it works.

Am I doing something wrong in the first example? When I print Vector2.length() it gives me a float with the value 0, but somehow this still gets through the if condition. Hence, I am confused.

Comment: Seems strange. I would say your code *should* work. Is the error really thrown at that code or do you have other calls to `normalize` somewhere else? If you don't use a debugger add `print(direction)` between the `if ...` and `...normalize()` lines and see what's printed immediately before the exception is thrown.

Comment: hey, I did try that. normalize works perfectly fine and no error is generated. Hence why I am so confused

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing a vector is nothing else than dividing the components of a vector by is length. Compute the length of the vector and divide the vector by the length if it is not 0:

```py
dir_len = direction.length()
if direction.length() != 0:
    velocity = direction / dir_len
```